# Scrollview pushes down on absolute positioned view

Tags: android, react-native, expo, frontend

The code has a scrollview of component cards and an absolutely positioned bottom navigation bar. When the contents of scrollview increase it should go below the navigation bar and should be scrollable, but the scrollview pushes the navigation bar. Please provide a fix for this code.

Images :
Before and after changing components

[image: Before Increasing components]

[image: After Increasing components]

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Text, View, ScrollView, StyleSheet, Image, TouchableOpacity, Alert, SafeAreaView, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import { useRoute } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { getName } from '../firebaseConnect';
import { useFonts, Montserrat_400Regular, Montserrat_700Bold } from '@expo-google-fonts/montserrat';
import { StatusBar, Platform } from 'react-native';
import HomeScreenCard from '../Components/HomeScreenCard';
import complainImage from '../assets/ComplainLogo.png';
import QueryLogo from '../assets/QueryLogo.png';
import ProfileLogo from '../assets/ProfileLogo.png';

const statusBarHeight = Platform.OS === 'android' ? StatusBar.currentHeight : 20;

function WelcomeScreen() {

  function triggerNewComplaint() {
    Alert.alert("Register New Complaint Logic"); //Create New Complaint Logic
  }
  function triggerNewQuery() {
    Alert.alert("Register New Query Logic"); //Create New Query Logic
  }

  const route = useRoute();
  const userId = route.params.userId;
  const [userName, setUserName] = useState(null);

  let [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    Montserrat_400Regular,
    Montserrat_700Bold,
  });

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUserName = async () => {
      try {
        const name = await getName(userId);
        setUserName(name);
        // Simulate loading for a few seconds
        setTimeout(() => setLoading(false), 2000); // 3000 milliseconds = 3 seconds
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching user name:', error);
      }
    };
    fetchUserName();
  }, [userId]);

  if (!fontsLoaded || loading) {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center", width: "100%", height: "100%" }}>
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" />
      </View>
    ); // Needs a loading screen
  } else {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.WelcomeTextWrapperContainer}>
          <View style={styles.WelcomeTextWrapper}>
            <Text style={styles.WelcomeText}>Welcome, {userName || 'loading...'}.  </Text>
          </View>
        </View>

        <View style={styles.NavigationBarContainer}>
          <View style={styles.NavigationBarWrapper}>
            <TouchableOpacity>
              <Image source={QueryLogo} style={styles.resizeComplainLogo}></Image>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity>
              <Image source={complainImage} style={styles.resizeComplainLogo}></Image>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity>
              <Image source={ProfileLogo} style={styles.resizeComplainLogo}></Image>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>

        <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.MainPageContainer} scrollEnabled={true}>
          <HomeScreenCard
            title="New Complaint"
            description="Contact our officials to register a complaint and interact with them to resolve your issues"
            imageSource={complainImage}
            onPress={triggerNewComplaint}
          />
          <HomeScreenCard
            title="New Query"
            description="Contact our officials to resolve a query and interact with them to gain more insights"
            imageSource={QueryLogo}
            onPress={triggerNewQuery}
          />
          
        </ScrollView>

      </View>
    );
  }

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#483670',
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingTop: statusBarHeight,
  },
  WelcomeTextWrapperContainer: {
    alignSelf: "flex-start",
    padding: 10,
    width: '100%',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  WelcomeTextWrapper: {
    backgroundColor: '#222222',
    borderRadius: 20,
    alignItems: 'center',
    width: '100%',
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  WelcomeText: {
    fontFamily: 'Montserrat_700Bold',
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 30,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  MainPageContainer: {
    borderTopLeftRadius: 30,
    borderTopRightRadius: 30,
    backgroundColor: '#e9e4f5',
  },
  resizeComplainLogo: {
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    padding: 5,
  },
  NavigationBarContainer: {
    width: "100%",
    position: "absolute",
    backgroundColor: "#0c0326",
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    height: 50,
    zIndex: 100, // Should make this responsive to layout
  },
  NavigationBarWrapper: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-evenly",
    height: 50,
  },
});

export default WelcomeScreen;
```

Comment: Remove flexGrow and paddingTop from container style and add FlexGrow on MainPageContainer. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Your welcome `View` pushes all the elements below down. You can fix it by wrapping the `ScrollView` in another `View` and adding height to that `View` like this

`height: Dimensions.get('screen').height - {your_wellcome_view_height}`. Hope it work :))